# iPhone SDK - Using the Speaker / Clicker / Beeper on a 1st Gen iPod

Tags: iphone

My current need is to provide an audio cue for an application with a timer, that would work on 1st gen ipods (i.e. iPods without a speaker).

I know that the bundled clock application of the iPod can use the internal speaker/beeper/clicker to show that the timer has run out.

Is there an api to interact with this speaker ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use the piezo speaker, you need:
Framework: `AudioToolbox.framework`
Header: `#import "AudioToolbox/AudioToolbox.h"`
Function: `AudioServicesPlayAlertSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);`

> Please note that sound will come through only if the user hasn't deactivated it in it's iPod/iPhone preference. This code will also make an iPhone vibrate if vibration is activated on the phone.