# Alert noise for iPod touch 1G

Tags: objective-c, ipod-touch

I know the iPod touch 1g does not have a speaker like the 2g, and the iPhone, but I do know that it has a small speaker, capable of making various beeps. Is there a way to make the iPod touch 1g beep, or does it only work on 2g and above? If so, what would the code be?

Thanks,

HiGuy

Comment: For AppStore or not? AFAIK you can't interact with the piezo clicker by SDK.

Comment: Then I'll have it for the iPod Touch, since I have one to test with.

Answer (score 0):

link for solution. (provided from the historic perspective only)

[iPhone SDK - Using the Speaker / Clicker / Beeper on a 1st Gen iPod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1804233/iphone-sdk-using-the-speaker-clicker-beeper-on-a-1st-gen-ipod)